# Jasig CAS Server 3.5.2 Build Failure with Maven-3

Tags: maven, maven-3, cas, jasig

I've been trying to build the Jasig CAS Server 3.5.2. on a CentOS6 machine. After running `mvn package install` however, I've receive the following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Tests run: 13, Failures: 0, Errors: 13, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.184 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  testAddTicketToCache(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testGetNullTicket(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testGetNonExistingTicket(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testGetExistingTicketWithInproperClass(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testGetNullTicketWithoutClass(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testGetNonExistingTicketWithoutClass(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testGetExistingTicket(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testDeleteExistingTicket(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testDeleteNonExistingTicket(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testDeleteNullTicket(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testGetTicketsIsZero(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testGetTicketsFromRegistryEqualToTicketsAdded(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)
  testGetExistingTicketWithProperClass(org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.JBossCacheTicketRegistryTests)

Tests run: 13, Failures: 0, Errors: 13, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Jasig Central Authentication Service .............. SUCCESS [1.713s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS Core .................................... SUCCESS [1:16.725s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS Web Application ......................... SUCCESS [16.249s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS Generic Support ......................... SUCCESS [0.704s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS JDBC Support ............................ SUCCESS [0.483s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS LDAP Support ............................ SUCCESS [2.986s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS Legacy Support .......................... SUCCESS [0.677s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS OpenId Support .......................... SUCCESS [4.758s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS RADIUS Support .......................... SUCCESS [0.539s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS SPNEGO/NTLM Support ..................... SUCCESS [0.761s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS Trusted User Support .................... SUCCESS [0.961s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS X.509 Client Certificate Support ........ SUCCESS [2.880s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS OAuth Support ........................... SUCCESS [1.871s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS JBoss Cache Integration ................. FAILURE [3.912s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS Memcached Integration ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Jasig CAS Ehcache Integration ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Jasig CAS Restlet Integration ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Jasig CAS - Uber WAR .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Jasig CAS Documentation ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Jasig CAS ClearPass Extension ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:55.953s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 05 10:26:55 GMT-05:00 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test (default-test) on project cas-server-integration-jboss: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/user/cas-server-3.5.2/cas-server-integration-jboss/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test (default-test) on project cas-server-integration-jboss: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/user/cas-server-3.5.2/cas-server-integration-jboss/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/user/cas-server-3.5.2/cas-server-integration-jboss/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.execute(SurefirePlugin.java:629)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cas-server-integration-jboss
```

Here's some of the system information from the Maven.

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 10:22:22-0500)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I've tried searching up solutions to similar problems, but I haven't had much success so far. I've been trying to read through the logs myself, but as I'm rather unfamiliar with both Maven and CAS, it's not been of much help.

If you need any other information, just ask.

[Edit] Here's the a sample from the test results from /home/user/cas-server-3.5.2/cas-server-integration-jboss/target/surefire-reports. All the other errors are essentially the same.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ticketRegistry' defined in class path resource [jbossTestContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cache' while setting bean property 'cache'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cache' defined in class path resource [jbossTestContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.jboss.cache.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.jboss.cache.RPCManagerImpl.start() on object instance org.jboss.cache.RPCManagerImpl@12998f87
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same Error message while trying to compile CAS 3.4.11 on RHEL5 X86_64

The solution turned out to be [ insufficient memory ] on the host running maven to compile it.

This was not obvious from reading the log files, but started showing up blatantly while running the 
"mvn install" command repeatedly a few times, [out of memory] errors started bubbling to the surface.

I was using a virtual machine with 2 GB, shut it down and reconfigured it with 4 GB and ran
"mvn install" again and it succeeded in finishing and depositing a WAR file in /opt/cas-server-3.4.11/cas-server-webapp/target/cas.war ~ 19 MB

Results:

```
...
[INFO] JA-SIG CAS X.509 Client Certificate Support ....... SUCCESS [12.916s]
[INFO] JA-SIG CAS JBoss Cache Integration ................ SUCCESS [32.418s]
[INFO] JA-SIG CAS BerkeleyDB Integration ................. SUCCESS [10.043s]
[INFO] JA-SIG CAS Memcached Integration .................. SUCCESS [3.128s]
[INFO] JA-SIG CAS Restlet Integration .................... SUCCESS [4.394s]
[INFO] Jasig CAS - Uber WAR .............................. SUCCESS [4.399s]
[INFO] CAS Documentation ................................. SUCCESS [0.025s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:38.004s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 11 23:13:34 CDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[root@signon cas-server-3.4.11]#
```